# Maximal Convex Hull in Integer Grid

Tags: geometry, optimization, convex-optimization, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

**What set of points on the $256 \times 256$ integer grid maximizes the number of vertices in its convex hull?**

For the full context, I was given an assignment to test algorithms that find the vertices of the convex hull of a set of points in $2D$. One natural thing to test is when we set the input set such that all the vertices (size $n$) are convex hull vertices (size $h$). In other words, the case when $n=h$. One major restriction was that the synthetic vertices I generate need to be **integer pairs in $[0, 32767]^2$.** To further clarify, co-linear points are not considered part of the convex hull (hence I want maximum number vertices). I quickly ran into issues because the trivial way of putting the vertices around the circumference of a circle no longer worked as I end up with something like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vA9Fa.png) (range smaller here to highlight issue). Indeed, the maximum $h$ I could produce was very small (around $2000$).

I already talked with my professor and they told me it's possible to make $h \gg 2000$ but I don't personally believe it, so before I go to them again I'd like to know if it's possible to prove the fundamental limit to how large $h$ can get (an expression for a low upper bound).

Comment: I think you should [edit] to change some wording. The convex hull  includes the interior points. You want to maximize the _number of vertices_ of the convex hull. Then your discussion of collinear points on the boundary makes more sense.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks! Indeed that makes it more clear what I mean.

Comment: Some possibly relevant posts [Convex Lattice Polygon In a given region](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4501395) and [Number of points on Convex hull with lattice points](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/62183), and [this AoPS post](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2560485p21935544)

Comment: according to the post given by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4501395/convex-lattice-polygon-in-a-given-region, the maximum number of vetices is $4 m^{2/3}$, where $m=256$ in your case, that makes the maximum number becomes around 160. If $m=32768$,  then it is 4096.

Comment: Note that $4096\not\!\gg2000$.