# Maximizing the Number of Vertices for a Regular n-gon Within a Specific Integer Coordinate Range

Tags: geometry, number-theory

I'm interested in identifying the largest possible number of vertices () for a regular
-gon that can be formed within an integer coordinate plane. The constraints of my problem are as follows:

- The plane is defined by the coordinate range $[0,32767]^2$
- Each vertex of the n-gon corresponds to a unique integer pair $(x,y)$.

the context of this problem is that I am really trying to find the greatest number of coordinates forming a convex hull (excluding colinear points) within this range.

Comment: I doubt that the answer to this question is the answer to the problem you describe in the last paragraph. You have a lot more freedom to construct just any convex polygon than you have to place a regular polygon on an integer lattice.

Comment: Isn't the answer n=4 ?

Comment: This related question may be what you are looking for: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4874973/maximal-convex-hull-in-integer-grid#comment10394729_4874973

Answer (score 2):

[Niven's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem) feels relevant.

If all corners have rational coordinates, then the center has rational coordinates as well: sum up all corners and divide by $n$.

So the vector $v_i$ from center to corner $i$ will have rational coordinates. If all corners have equal distance from the center, then you get the angle $\alpha$ which two consecutive corners form with the center characterized as

$$\cos\alpha=\frac{\langle v_i,v_{i+1}\rangle}{\langle v_i,v_i\rangle}$$

This is rational as well. Also, if your polygon is regular you have

$$\alpha=\frac{2\pi}{n}$$

So you have a rational fraction of the full angle (or equivalently a rational number of degrees), and it's cosine is rational too. That doesn't leave you a lot of options, since the above theorem states that $\cos\alpha\in\{0,\pm\frac12,\pm1\}$ are the only possibilities, and you can quickly exclude the cases of $n=3$ and $n=6$.

The integers you have in your question are merely a special case of rational numbers. So they can't allow for more solutions, and you can verify that they don't force you down to fewer solutions either.